# Why is the instrumentation amp distorting the signal on the input?

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, high-pass-filter

Here's my schematic. A current source is driving a resistive sensor. The sine wave is to mimic the behavior of the current real supply and doesn't play a role in the distortion. It's approximately constant.

[image: Sinewave Distortion]

The distortion goes away if I disconnect the signal from the in-amp input, so it must have something to do with how the bias current is handled.

I can put a 200n cap between the two rails and that cleans up the signal nicely, but it substantially attenuates the signal. It's not too bad with a 50n cap.

[image: Corrected with cap]

Playing around with the values for the high pass filters, but maintaining the same cutoff, I can see that the plot gets smoother for smaller C and more jagged with bigger C.

Through trial and error I settled on this design. I hesitate to go lower with the capacitors, because that would require larger resistors and I don't want to introduce too much thermal noise.
BW is limited from 800Hz to 3kHz.

[image: final circuit]

Is there any way to improve this further? I'm losing about 10% of the signal on the input side.
Also, why the two distinct bumps in on the V+ and V- nodes?

Updates:
I should have had the current source drawing from the +9v rail to better represent the real regulator. I have also adjusted the output filter according to @SpehroPefhany which eliminated the distinct nodes and reduced attenuation a bit.
I like the idea of lowering the cutoff frequency to save a bit of the signal by @jonk, but I did set it to 800Hz with the intent of minimizing the bandwidth to minimize noise. I'll see what the noise simulations show before I decide to go lower than 800Hz.

Here's an updated schematic:
[image: Updated Circuit]

[Datasheet for AD8429](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8429.pdf)

Comment: Sanity checks first. You are going to be -1 dB already with your RC filters (1500 Hz, I gather.) That's about 10% loss. You say it is, too. So I guess you confirm theory by simulation. Am I correct that \$78.995\:\Omega \le R_1 \le 79.005\:\Omega\$? If so, I have an answer for you.

Comment: @jonk That's correct

Comment: I note the updated schematic.

Comment: I finally got a moment to look, again. (Work kept me busy, today.) Quick question from the 10 seconds of time I just had to look. How is it that your (-) opamp input is anything other than AC-grounded to the -9 V rail? C5 (bottom schematic) just hard-nails it, doesn't it? I don't know much about your transducer (R1) and I certainly do not know how to properly drive it. But the opamp is an instrumentation opamp and your R1 transducer has one end tied straight to the -9 V rail. What does C5 achieve, exactly? You could show C5 and R1 separately tied to the -9 V rail and no wire between them.

Comment: In short, how [is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8fPo.png) any different? (They are the same schematic, true?) I just want to be sure we are seeing the same thing.

Comment: @jonk Yes, I would say that's equivalent. My intention with C5 was to level shift the signal up to ground. If I try to put -9v into the in-amp, it doesn't work. If I connect V- directly to ground, the circuit still works, but the output would then be centered around -2.5v since the DC of V+ is about 2.5mV. The simulation is constantly breaking when I try to make changed, so it's hard for me to figure out what exactly is going on.

Comment: I think the high pass on the -9v rail basically just adds about -2.5mV DC to the in-amp V- rail. The other purpose is also to eliminate common mode noise. C4 and C5 will both be connected close to the BNC connector for the transducer.

Comment: I have some more changes to the circuit. I tried the cap and resistor values closer to those you suggested and the noise sim showed less noise, which makes sense now that I think about it. I also made them asymmetric to balance the DC offset on the input. I may just make another post soon, since the distortion problem seems to be solved here.

Comment: Okay. I'll wait to see. (Qualitatively speaking, I don't like tethering one end of the sensor to a supply rail, though, when you are using that instrumentation opamp.)

Answer (score 7):

I believe the problem lies in the placement of just one wire in your schematic.

Try this:

[image]

I've kept the RC time constant the same, but chose somewhat differently for the resistor and capacitor values. The input bias current is at most \$300\:\text{nA}\$ and the offset is at most about \$100\:\text{nA}\$. I'd say that \$100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ bias resistors are plenty low. I would not go lower than that. Maybe higher. But this means larger capacitors. Which I used. Feel free to make your own judgements, but keep in mind that you are driving the bases of BJTs with emitters tied to \$3\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistors according to the simplified schematic in the datasheet. I think \$1\:\text{k}\Omega\$ to ground is quite excessive.

The main problem in your schematic is solved with \$R_5\$ in my schematic. You just needed to float your input, while providing a slight galvanic connection to satisfy Spice.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this circuit won't work with my constant current source. I simplified it for the post, but the constant current source is powered by the +9 and -9v rails. It has to sink to -9v or there isn't enough headroom for the regulators. I need lots of headroom for ripple rejection.

Comment: @griffin175 Understood. I addressed what I could see about your simulation setup. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 7):

The bumps come from the current flowing into the output capacitor with those "real" 0.65 ohm resistances, and since you have coupled the inputs through the (-) power supply rather than ground, they appear as a significant (in terms of the gain of 1,000) common-mode voltage at the inputs.

[image]

With 100x the output resistor and 1/100 the output capacitor:

[image]

Better regulated supplies, coupling to ground (preferred) and decreasing the output load will all reduce the CM voltage change.

With lower power supply resistances:

[image]